# Jmeter Performance testing for SSRS reports retures Error in the Response page

Tags: jmeter

I have a aspx webpage which is integrated with SSRS reports.I want to perform a performance test using Jmeter,I used the Jmeter HTTP(S) script recorder for the same.
It was seen that the response data captured by Jmeter returns error message stating as below

Report Viewer Configuration Error
The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

and will not the show the report data as the response though the POST was successfull.

In the above context the jmeter test is intended to test the response time of reports.

Could anyone please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance,
Theju

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to modern web applications, record and replay may not work as there could be some dynamic parameters responsible for [preserving and controlling values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or protecting from [CSRF attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) so you will need to build you test as follows:

- Open 1st page

  - Detect all dynamic parameters and convert them into [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- Open 2nd page providing dynamic parameters extracted in the previous step

The process is known as **correlation** and you can find a plenty of articles by searching "JMeter correlation" over the web.

Check out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for real-life example related to ASP web apps.